# Not showing device in target window after Android Studio update 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, updates

I recently updated my Android Studio to 2.3. Now it doesn't show my usb device(Sony C2305) in `Select Deployment Target` window which was working fine just before updating. When I connect my android device through USB `Nothing to show` is displayed in `Select Deployment Target` window. When I disconnect it, all emulators are showing.

Device is shown in `Android Monitor`, so connection is fine. But not displaying in `Select Deployment Target` window. 
Eveything was fine just before Android Studio updating to 2.3

[image]

Comment: Exactly the same problem here too.

Comment: @Steve: I solved the issue. please see my answer. Happy coding..

Comment: Yes, that works for me too! I don't see "Firebase plugin", but I have "Firebase App Indexing", "Firebase Services" and "Firebase Testing." I just disabled them all, and the problem magically went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked stack traces of studio and found that the issue was due to some error in *Firebase plugin* after Android Studio update. I'm not even using firebase in current project so I don't know how that makes a problem. I just disable firebase plugin and then now my device is showing in the `Select Deployment Target` window.

Answer (score 2):

1)disconnect and connect again device

2) go win taskManger 
         process tab 
         select adb.exe and click endtask
      cancel device chooser and check again

Comment: I have tried all the basic techniques like restarting etc.

Comment: sometime i face same issue because of data cable not plugin correctly

Comment: Device is detecting by android studio and i can see it in android monitor. But not showing in 'Select Deployment Target'

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 2.3 v162.3764568 this issue occurs due to a crash in Firebase Testing plugin.

**Solution**: Disable Firebase Testing plugin by going to File -> Settings and select Plugins on the left. Search for Firebase Testing and uncheck it and then click on Apply and OK.

Restart Android Studio and the issue is fixed for now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I solved the issue before by disabling the plugin

Comment: Thanks Work for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Open console in android studio and try this :
adb kill-server ,
adb start-server ,
and,
adb devices